# Error with JEST tests on TRAVIS-CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, jestjs

**Error**

```
Error: /home/travis/build/ElectronicaGitHub/pictureAvenue/node_modules/jest-
cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/
Release/contextify.node: invalid ELF header
```

That's happening when i'm trying to start JEST tests, it's just example test from JEST tutorial and looks like

```
jest.dontMock('../sum');

describe('sum', function() {
 it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
   var sum = require('../sum');
   expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
 });
});
```

Locally test with JEST runs fine.

Tried to start **mocha** tests on **travis-ci** and it's ok!

But my project on ReactJS and i they advise to use JEST for tests.

How to fix that problem?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem when trying to run Jest inside a docker container (the [node-0.10](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jolicode/node-0.10/) repository to be precise). Will put my solution here if I manage to get it to work.

Comment: Seems like this error might be occurring because some binaries under `node_modules` were being built for an incorrect platform. [One user had this issue](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/3#issuecomment-1984632) and solved it by re-running `npm install` on the same platform as the app would be running in. You might want to check that `node_modules` isn't being deployed to TravisCI, and instead, `npm install` is being run at some point by TravisCI.

Answer (score 0):

Found your project on GH: https://github.com/ElectronicaGitHub/pictureAvenue

Almost guaranteed that this is because you checked in the `node_modules` folder.  This should be downloaded by each consumer of the project, using `npm install`.  Add a `.gitignore` file to the root of your project with the following content:

> node_modules

Before you do this, you'll need to do:

`rm -fr node_modules && \ 
    git commit -a -m 'remove node_modules from source control' && \ 
    git push origin master`

Then add your `.gitignore` file and do another commit.

While you're at it, it looks like you're also checking in your sass-cache (`.sass-cache\*`).  You'll want to do the same thing.

Final thoughts:

Typically source control is great for any artifact or code, it is not great for things that are often OS dependent (like `node_modules`) or host dependent (`.sass-cache`).

Hope that helps.